# Selecting an interceptor based on a facility created ILogger

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I have two types of interceptors: LoggingWithDebugInterceptor and LoggingInterceptor.
I am using the Castle Logging Facility and I am wondering how to write a selector that registers an interceptor on my container for any type that implements ILoggable according to the ILogger's IsDebugEnabled property that was created by the Castle Logging Facility.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't.

Configure that at your logging framework's level.